# How do you properly loop through an Xml file and display the values in a TextBox?

Tags: xml, winforms

I want to loop through a xml file and display the values in text box, but my textbox is showing only one value at a time. In debug mode I am able to see all values. Here is my code.

```
void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(@"D:\satish1\na.xml");
    var query = from p in xd.Descendants("item")
                select new
                {
                    //name = p.Element("title").Value,
                    des = p.Element("description").Value
                };
    foreach (var p in query)
    {
        //tbs.Text = p.name.ToString();
        title.Text = p.des.ToString();
    }
}
```

How would I repeat all the values continously; my timer's TimeSpan is 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ***foreach***, hence when ever your code exits the function, you will have only last value assigned to the text box. Do something like this:

```
//Have one private variable, to store data from XML
private int _counter = 0;
private List<string> _xmlData = new List<string>();

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(_xmlData.Count == 0) //Populate your list
    {
        _counter = 0;
        XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(@"D:\satish1\na.xml");
        var query = from p in xd.Descendants("item")
            select new
            {
                des = p.Element("description").Value
            };
        foreach (var p in query) _xmlData.Add(p.des.ToString());
    }
    if(_counter < _xmlData.Count)
         title.Text = _xmlData[_counter];
    _counter++;
    //If you require
    if(_counter == _xmlData.Count)
    {
         timer.Stop(); //Stop the timer
         _xmlData.Clear();
         _counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.